# Не работает часть кода discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord.py

Команда должна выдавать информацию о сервере в лс дс, но выдаёт ошибку при использовании команды:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам код:

```
@bot.command()
async def info(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    bebrus = await ctx.guild.templates()
    for template in bebrus:
        await template.delete()

    temp = await ctx.guild.create_template(name=f"Шаблон сервера {ctx.guild}")

    emb = discord.Embed(description=f"""**Информация о сервере {ctx.guild}**

`ID:` {ctx.guild.id}
`Участников:` {len(ctx.guild.members)}
`Ролей:` {len(ctx.guild.roles)}
`Каналов:` {len(ctx.guild.channels)}
`Эмоджи:` {len(ctx.guild.emojis)}

`Создатель:` {ctx.guild.owner}
`Регион:` {ctx.guild.region}
`Дата создания:` {ctx.guild.created_at}
`Шаблон:` https://discord.new/{temp.code}

`Иконка гильдии:`""", color=0xbd0909)

    emb.set_image(url=f"{ctx.guild.icon_url}")

    await ctx.author.send(embed=emb)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)